# Why is there no "unavailable parameter" error in PHP functions/methods?

Tags: php

I just spent 10 minutes looking for a bug, when I found out I was passing something to a method as second parameter while it doesn't take more than 1 parameter. I had to pass it through some other way.

That's when my question arose: why doesn't PHP throw an error when you pass a non-available parameter?

Am I missing something - other than my own func_get_args answer?

```
function test($a)
{

}

test('a', 'b'); // no error, but no 2nd parameter in test().
```

Comment: can you add the function code ??? Some validation must be there

Comment: @Robin v. G. i see what you mean now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only answer I can personally think of:

[func_get_args](http://php.net/func_get_args) enables you to dynamically fetch parameters from function calls, making any number of parameters valid.